# django using xhr change image from db(sqlite)

Tags: ajax, django, database, sqlite, xmlhttprequest

I want to load two images from sqlite(db) using xhr, and when click one image than the data will be send to server (asynchronous) and two images will be change to next images from db. now i have no errors but i can't see image on browser. i think json - django - db connection is not correct.

i wrote code now only for one image. please teach me

**survey.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onload = function () {

        {%  for wheel in wheels|slice:"1:2" %}

        xhr.open('GET', '{{ wheel.wheel_sample.url }}', true);

        var img = new Image();
        var response = xhr.responseText;
        var binary = ""

        for(i=0;i<response.length;i++){
            binary += String.fromCharCode(response.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff);
        }

        img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + btoa(binary);
        var canvas = document.getElementById('showImage');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        context.drawImage(img,0,0);

        {% endfor %}
    }

    xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plane; charset=x-user-defined');
    xhr.send();

</script>

<div class="wheels-img-container">
    <canvas class="wheel-first" id="showImage" onclick="img1_click();" width="135" height="135"/>
    <canvas class="wheel-second" id="showImage2" onclick="img2_click();" width="135" height="135"/>
</div>
```

**views.py**

```
def survey(request):
    json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")()
    wheels = json_serializer.serialize(Wheel.objects.all(), ensure_ascii=False)
    return render(request, 'polls/survey.html', {'wheels' : wheels})
```

**models.py**

```
image_storage = FileSystemStorage(
      # Physical file location ROOT
      location='/media/'.format(settings.MEDIA_ROOT),
      # Url for file
      base_url='/media/'.format(settings.MEDIA_URL),
  )

def image_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/media/<filename>
    return 'media/{0}'.format(filename)

def logo_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/dashboard/picture/<filename>
    return 'media/{0}'.format(filename)

class Wheel(models.Model):
    wheel_sample = models.ImageField(blank=True, 
    upload_to=image_directory_path, storage=image_storage)
    wheel_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: Where in your code do you download the next image? I only see a single place where you inline the first image as base64. This will never load a new image. I recommend that you make the images available under an URL `media/` and request the initial and the new image via an `<img>` tag and change the `src` attribute of that tag.

Comment: what i wrote at the top is as final result. first of all i wanted to load image from db using xhr. 22 images are already an URL media/ and <img> tag and src i can copy and paste. but now i can't see any image on web. is there any wrong code or way in javascript?